# JavaScript - reading JSON file with require gives different result than fs.readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, require, fs

I'm getting an issue that makes me think there's something I'm missing about how `require` works in JavaScript.  Basically, if I use `require` to read a JSON file, I get a different result than using `fs.readFileSync`.

I start with a JSON file with the following contents:

```
{"text":"old text"}
```

I first read the file with `require` and `fs.readFileSync` and get the same results for each.  I then update the file with `fs.writeFileSync` and read the file again with `require` and `fs.readFileSync`, but I get different results after updating.

It's important to note that I'm requiring the file from inside a function.  I would expect this to import the file separately with each function call, but that's apparently not what's happening.  Just wondering if someone can explain exactly what's happening.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const textPath = './test.json';

const oldTextJSON = getText();  // prints as "old text"
const oldTextRead = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(textPath)).text;  // prints as "old text"

fs.writeFileSync(textPath, JSON.stringify({
  text: "new text"
}));

const newTextJson = getText();  // prints as "old text"
const newTextRead = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(textPath)).text;  // prints as "new text"

function getText() {
  return require(textPath).text;
}
```

Comment: Require caches results. Multiple calls to require don’t reread the file.

Comment: @MarkMeyer is right, it's just I prefer to think of it in a different way. Require doesn't read the file, it imports node module. And how is node module imported? It's loaded to the memory once and then injected to all places.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is more obvious when a file is required by multiple files - adding a `console.log` to the top of the required file won't result in the same thing getting logged multiple times.  However, in most cases either 1) `require` is used at the top of another file where it would more obviously be held in memory or 2) the result of the `require` statement would not change.  Either way, it makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this one line explain the characteristics of `require`.

```
const path = require("path");


const filepath = path.resolve(textPath);
delete require.cache[filepath];
```

Basically require reads from the **cache** no matter how many times you call.

Comment: So `delete require.cache[filepath]` does nothing here?  It doesn't seem to be changing anything when added before `require(textPath).text` in the function.

Comment: It deletes the require cache. and then if you require again , it takes the new file content